# How to get text from html list received from BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a page with a lot of links with same class name. I am using BeautifulSoup for this pupose and used find_all() with attribute conditions. Python gives the following output:

```
[<a href="something" id="something" class="something">Click Me!!!<font color="red">34344</font></a>,<a href="something" id="something" class="something">Click Me!!!<font color="red">34344</font></a>,<a href="something" id="something" class="something">Click Me!!!<font color="red">34344</font></a>,....]
```

From above response, I want to get "Click Me!!!" from whole list. I tried following:

- get_text()
- .string

But nothing worked. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.text`.
This works for me:

```py
b=soup.find_all("a")
text=b[0].text
print(text) #prints out text from b[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Agent Biscutt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15475598/agent-biscutt)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69658788), but it extracts all the matches and gets the first one and gets the text, which is much less efficient than directly only extracting the first match, with `find`:

```
print(soup.find('a').text)
```